# Is componentDidMount supposed to run with shallow rendering in Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

From my understanding and from what I have read so far in various answers, not all lifecycle methods are supposed to be run with shallow rendering. Especially `componentDidMount`

However, I notice that when I do

```
  beforeEach(function () {
    fakeComponentDidMount = sinon.stub(Component.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
    fakeComponentDidMount.callsFake(function () {});
    wrapper = shallow(<Component {...props} />);
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    fakeComponentDidMount.restore();
  });

  it('calls componentDidMount', function () {
    expect(fakeComponentDidMount.called).to.equal(true);
  });
```

the test passes.

So, am I doing something wrong here or have I understood something wrong?

[For reference](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/465#issuecomment-227697726)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes it is in `enzyme 3.0`.

https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300

[`LifeCycleExperimental`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/678) which was previously an option that you had to manually set to true on `shallow` is now enabled by default because it is now stable.

This is much nicer than having to resort to `mount` when wanting to test lifecycles.

There is absolutely no excuse to not use `shallow` for unit tests now :)... Well apart from when you need to test refs :(.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks. Does this mean that all lifecycle methods execute now with a `shallow` render? I think I may open up a PR where we document what lifecycle methods run in each render type

Comment: @DimitrisKaragiannis I think so. You could just quickly test each render lifecycle to be sure.

Comment: I'm on version 3.3.0 and componentDidMount is not getting called during a shallow render but componentWillMount does. Anyone have an idea what's going on? @DimitrisKaragiannis did you get this working?

Comment: @DanielSunYang That's weird. It definitely works on 3.0 because I tried it. Can you try 3.0 instead? It may be a bug in a later package. Do: `npm uninstall enzyme` and then `npm install --save-dev enzyme@3.0`. If this still doesn't work then something must be wrong with your setup and you will need to post a SO question.