# How to call ComponentDidMount when testing with Jest in React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I've a component , where ComponentDidMount is trying to call a API function

```
componentDidMount(){

   this.getTypes(this.props.user).then(Response => {this.setState({List: Response.Types })});

  }

async getTypes(userLogin){
    try{
      res = await API.get(......... );
      } 
    catch(error) {
       ....
       }
}
```

Now i would like to invoke componentDidMount & getTypes and will mock API.get.

So to do this, can anyone tell me how to invoke both componentDidMount & getTypes using Jest?

EDIT : Tried to do in this way . But i can see that its not invoking the ComponentDidMount .

```
 it('renders ComponentDidMount',  () => {
               const wrapper = shallow(<HoldVendor region={"aaa"} applier={"xxx"} />);
               API.get = jest.fn().mockImplementation(
                () => {                                                      
                       return {"Types": [{}]};
               });

 expect(API.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use [Enzyme](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/) to test ur components.

In tests, shallow render your component as

`shallow(<ComponentName {...props} />)`

this will automatically call `componentDidMount`.

Now to mock the api call, you can use [nock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock) or even mock the entire Api.get method before you render the component in your tests.

Comment: Thanks. Updated the question , can you please check & let me know where it is going wrong.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47309585/is-componentdidmount-supposed-to-run-with-shallow-rendering-in-enzyme answer if you are on older version of enzyme.  Lifecycle experimental option was there in older versions. But in the latest, it automatically calls the componentDidMount on shallow rendering itself.

Also u need to mock your call before you render the component. otherwise it will be actual function call instead of your mock.